# How can i get column values in different language in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

A have MySQL table that contains text in two languages - english and russian. It is possible to select only english or only russian values?

Comment: How are they stored in the database? Please add your database schema to the question.

Comment: that values are from one table, so i dont need any joins

Comment: I have some stuff in a cupboard. Can I make spaghetti bolognese with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how your data is stored exactly, but if each language is stored in a separate row, then you can use a `WHERE` statement. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `language` = 'EN'
```

Comment: Then how do you identify languages? I can't help you without knowing how your schema looks like.

Comment: Schema and data samples, please